# How do I scramble?

Tags: madden-17

When controlling the quarterback on a passing play, you're supposed to be able to hold the right trigger (sprint button) to start scrambling and take off running.

However, it usually doesn't work out. The quarterback seems to ignore the scramble button, and instead slowly step forward as if you're still trying to hang in the pocket.

Sometimes, I will press the scramble button, and he'll start to move, but I'll let go of it for a moment to slow down and turn, like I would with a running back. This is a disaster. He not only stops sprinting, but plants and sets his feet again like he's going to throw. Instant sack.

How can I effectively get the quarterback to forget about passing and just take off running down the field?

I'm playing on Xbox One, in case it's relevant.